# adding a border in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create an image that adds a border to an existing image on Java by copying the pixels from their old locations to new coordinates. My solution is working, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient/shorter way to do this.

```
 /** Create a new image by adding a border to a specified image. 
 * 
 * @param p
 * @param borderWidth  number of pixels in the border
 * @param borderColor  color of the border.
 * @return
 */
    public static NewPic border(NewPic p, int borderWidth, Pixel borderColor) {
    int w = p.getWidth() + (2 * borderWidth); // new width
    int h = p.getHeight() + (2 * borderWidth); // new height

    Pixel[][] src = p.getBitmap();
    Pixel[][] tgt = new Pixel[w][h];

    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            if (x < borderWidth || x >= (w - borderWidth) || 
                y < borderWidth || y >= (h - borderWidth))
                    tgt[x][y] = borderColor;
            else 
                tgt[x][y] = src[x - borderWidth][y - borderWidth];

        }
    }

    return new NewPic(tgt);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is only for presentation to the screen, and the intent is not to actually add a border to the image, but to have the image present to the screen with a border, [the component that is displaying your image can be configured with a border](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).

```
component.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(
                                4, 4, 4, 4, Color.BLACK));
```

would present a 4 pixel (on each edge) border drawn in black.

However, if the intent is to really redraw the image, then I'd approach it by grabbing each row array, and then using a ByteBuffer and copying in the row array (and border elements) with a bulk `put(...)` operation, then grabbing the entire ByteBuffer's contents as an array to stuff back into the image.

Whether this makes any difference in performance is unknown, benchmark before and after this attempt at optimization, as the resulting code could actually be slower.

The main issue is that while the system Arrays functions allows bulk copying and filling of array contents, it doesn't provide a utility to do so into an offset on the destination array; however, the Buffers from the NIO package allow you to do that quite easily, so if a solution exists, it's in the NIO ByteBuffer or it's kin.